# Show administrative description in Views

Tags: views, 8, webforms

I am needing to do a Views report for all webforms on our site (we currently have 27 forms) that can show me the total submission count per form.

The issue I am having is that we need the Views report to also show the Administrative Description of the form but I do not see that as a field option in Views.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is one way to do it does however involve creating a custom twig Extension. its not to hard and there are a few youtube videos on the subject ... 
for others it is good to note that custom Twig Extensions has replaced php input fields in older versions of Drupal.

in a nut shell you create a custom module, 
you add a MODULENAME.services.yml  file.

in it you put...

```
services:
modulename.getWebformDescription:
  class: Drupal\modulename\getWebformDescriptionTwigExtension
  arguments: ['@entity_type.manager']
  tags:
    - { name: twig.extension }
```

then you need here is your class file (getWebformDescriptionTwigExtension.php)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\modulename;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;

/**
 * Provides twig function getWebformDescription()
 */
class getWebformDescriptionTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

  /**
   * Load entity type manager.
   *
   * @var EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getName() {
    return 'getWebformDescription';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFunctions() {
    return [
      new \Twig_SimpleFunction('getWebformDescription',
        [$this, 'getWebformDescription'], [
          'is_safe' => ['html'],
        ]),
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Provides getWebformDescription function to Twig templates.
   *
   * Use example {{ getWebformDescription( webfrom_id) }}.
   *
   * @param string webfrom_id
   *   The webform id eg 'contact'
   */
  public function getWebformDescription($webfrom_id) : string {
    // Invoke __toString and cast to int.
    $webfrom_id = $webfrom_id->__toString();
    $webform_storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('webform');
    $webform = $webform_storage->load($webfrom_id);
    return $webform->get('description');
  }

}
```

after all that is done and the module is enabled you can then in views add the webform id field (and exclude it from display)

then add a new custom field and look at the replacement patterns you will see 
some thing like {{webfrom_id}} ...

in that field you can then enter ...

```
 {{ getWebformDescription(webfrom_id) }}
```

if stuck 
see stuff like https://medium.com/@thihathit/extending-custom-twig-extension-to-drupal-8-twig-extension-class-d4b99c2177ae

or google "create custom twig extension for drupal 8"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you taggartJ

I feel like this question hasn't helped many people over the time since it's very specific, but it helped me.

I'm trying to do something similar in a Drupal 9 custom module:

```
function MY_MODULE_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  $view_id = $view->id();
  $view_title = $view->display_handler->getOption('title');
  $view_description = $view->storage->get('description');
  ...
}
```